# Dual brushed motors digital controller works on only one side

Tags: h-bridge, comparator, l298, filtering

I'm actually developing a way to control, digitally, the speed of brushed motors with a Raspberry Pi.

To do so, I use the following diagram where:

The raspberry controls the shift registers (purple) for which:

- pin 0 & 1 control the motor direction
- pin 2 to 7 control the motor speed (0 to 63) through a R/2R DAC (+2 potentiometers of adjust the output to the triangular wave)

The comparator (blue) receives:

- on one side the R/2R network output
- On the other, a "triangular waveform" (green)

The triangular waveform (green) is produced by the RC filter which receives a square wave from the Raspberry Pi.
The comparator resulting PWM is sent to the "enable" pin of the L298N H bridge and the outputs are at right with the needed diodes.

As the L298N has 2H bridges, I want to use it to control 2 motors.

**My setup works very fine on one side, but absolutely not on the other.**

[image: Schematic]

Here are some oscilloscope traces:

On the working side, the triangular wave and the R/2R output.
[image: Working side signals]

On the not working side, same signals with the same values but all messed up with some sort of parasites.
[image: Not working side signals]

Note : It shows 10V/ square when in fact it's 1V.
Both these traces have been taken at the same moment.

If I make the "working side" motor run alone, it works fine, but as soon as I start the other one, everything is parasited...
And if I try to run the "not working side" motor alone, it struggle to turn whatever speed I want.
I obviously exchanged the data inputs and the motors, but it really seems to come from the electronics
I really don't get it...

Here is the PCB layout:
[image: PCB layout]

And the actual PCB top side:
[image: real PCB top]

**Edit** : The traces of the 5V VCC power supply taken on the comparator +5V (most accessible pin ;) )

[image]

**Edit** :Ground layers of the actually missworking PCB and the one I intend to use (for Winny):
[image: Ground layers of old and new PCB]

Thanks by advance for your help :)

**PCB Update after "John Birckhead" comment/answer :**
(The bottom layer is highlited)

I re-did everything by hand and I'd like confirmation before making it as it is a long process with my small tools :)

I added the 5V and 9V capacitors as displayed. The 5V one should fit between the heat-sink fins ;)

- In white, the GND routes, separated between "power" (left) and "signal" (right), but both linked by the connector in the middle.
- I tired to do the same thing for the +5V
- I'll add a GND plane on the bottom face, I did not display it for readability reasons

[image]

**Update following all the advices**

Following @winny and @JohnBirckhead advice plus my few requirements, I've come to this :

1. No soldering pads on top side for components hiding them with their body to be able to solder them (variable resistors or connectors)
2. Ground plane on the bottom part only on the "command side"
3. As few as possible tracks cutting the ground plane
4. Tracks as short as possible.
5. 10µF SMD capacitors on every IC and the L298N 5V
6. 100µF SMD capacitor on the 9V close to the L298N

[image]

After confirmation of the viability of this PCB, I'll produce it.

Hoping this don't hurt the experts eyes ;)

Comment: Probably due to lack of ground plane and decoupling capacitors. Probe Vcc under load and post oscillogram.

Comment: @winny I have a ground plane on the other side ;) (btw, the ground tracks are separated from the ground plane, but the pads are linked to it, which is strange to me). I'll add the VCC oscillogramme in a few minutes

Comment: I dont see any capacitors at the supply inputs of the L298N chip. This is a big problem, block the 9 V line with 100 µF and the 5 V line with 10 µF using pin 8 as GND for all.

Comment: @winny I added the traces.

Comment: As @Jens said, there is no filtering on the 9V and 5V on the L298N, I'll try to solder some capacitors there for testing purpose and if it solves it, I'll be good to make a new PCB for the 4th time :)

Comment: Is there a small solder joint between 13 and 15 of L298N? The photo looks suspect there..

Comment: @jens No, it's fine, I checked all the connections 15 times, it's just a very crappy quality picture :)

Comment: @Jens Well, I added the capacitors, it seems to have improved the signal, but now both sides are not working anymore XD Should I change for bigger capacitors or electrolytic ones?

Comment: Horrible. If Vcc isn’t a flat line at all conditions, fix that first. Proper layer, possibly 4 layer. Proper strang decoupling.

Comment: @winny I can't make a 4 layers board, I'll have to stick with 2. What do you call a flat line?

Comment: How come? A flat horizontal line, straight DC with no noise. Neither if the two oscillograms show one. You have decoupling issues.

Comment: @winny Yes, and this is the point o this post, I updated my PCB and I'm wondering if it's worth producing it, as said in the edit at the bottom of the question

Comment: Please show your ground layer, just the copper.

Comment: @winny here it is, just over the answer to John

Comment: Is grey ground plane on top and bottom? If yes you need to join them with vias throughout. No islands. 4 layers is cheap these days and would simplify your layout a lot.

Comment: @winny No, the grey layer (GND) is just on the bottom plane. Should I also put it on the top? I'm producing the PCBs myself, no idea how to combine two 2 layers PCB into a 4 layer one ;)

Comment: No need in 2022. You get 4 layers for a few USD in low quantities. You bottom layer is absolutely crowded with long tracks destroying you ground plane. Keep all traces on top and only short tracks on bottom if needed to bridge something, or wire jumpers. Solid ground plane! Strong decoupling!

Answer (score 3):

This is a really nice effort, and your schematic will work with a couple of tweaks to your layout.  The only issue are your design's current paths.

Take a look at your layout below.  You have a ground plane but it must make way for the traces.  I have chosen one of your ground paths as an example, indicated
by the yellow arrows.

[image]

You can see that the ground for your R-2R network and comparator has to share the same path as that required by the motor power.  When the motor switches on or off, the instantaneous current, coupled with the resistance and inductance of your traces, means that the instantaneous voltage on the ground can differ  at different places along the path.  Since the power ground is also your reference, your comparator input signal is not clean and you get the results you have shown.

So you were on the right track when you made the comment about the ground pads being attached to the ground plane.  You never want your low-power grounds to carry high currents.  To solve your problem, lay out the board to route the return path with a
heavy trace directly to a single point - the ground pins of the LM192.  All of the diode grounds should have a separate path from this point, not shared with any of the other circuitry.  if you use a ground plane, do not attach any of these pads to the plane.  A separate ground trace should go to everything else in the circuit.  It wouldn't hurt to sprinkle in some decoupling capacitors - it's not the best practice to use a power rail as a reference voltage, so if you do, decouple the heck out of it.

You might experiment with cutting the offending traces and adding jumper wires from your power line to confirm this diagnosis.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I have a ground plane covering the whole bottom surface, I did not show it for readability purpose. If I understand right, I should separate the "high" (9V) power ground from the "low" power ground? But they will meet on the GND pin... So, one on one side, the other on the other side and a clear separation between (except GND pin), or should I put a capacitor in series to split them?

Comment: I updated the PCB and edited the question, could you give it a small look? :)

Comment: Btw, the side where you draw your arrows is the side that worked... It's the other side that was not working properly :(

Comment: Definitely an improvement.  I might suggest that if you can make a split or partial plane, that you do not extend your ground plane to the left half of the board.  You might also  add a large value (electrolytic?) capacitor between the +5 and ground and a ferrite bead in series, and place a larger 0.1 decoupling cap at each of the 5-V IC's.  This will help because no matter what you do to your board you still have the problem of the drop in the return line from your power supply. To improve the design, put in a regulator and derive the 5V from the 9V, which will solve the power supply problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I would like to keep the board as small as possible as there will be at least 4 others like it :) I already have decoupling caps on the ICs 5V input, but I noticed that their value was down by a magnitude of 100 (can't read properly apparently). My power supply is a 12V battery with 2 separate 5V and 9V buck regulators. So, you're saying to physically split the GND plane and have a link only on the GND pin between both sides? Or to have the plane only on the "control" stages?

Comment: I would do the latter - there is no need for a ground plane for the motors.  Your L298 would be the dividing line.

Comment: Could you give me your point of view on this (hopefully) last change? The main subject has been edited :)